# BrowserMob Proxy, Selenium. Page doesn't load

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

Now I am working on tests on python. I am using BrowserMob Proxy and Selenium to capture HTTP 
requests.

```
robot_globals = {'proxy': None, 'selenium': None}

def robot_setup():
    server = Server(settings.BROWSERMOB_PROXY_PATH, options={'port':     settings.BROWSERMOB_PROXY_PORT})
    server.start()
    proxy = server.create_proxy()
    proxy.selenium_proxy()
    if settings.BROWSER_TO_TEST == 'FIREFOX':
        from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

        selenium = WebDriver(proxy=proxy, timeout=10)
    elif settings.BROWSER_TO_TEST == 'CHROME':
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
        selenium = WebDriver(executable_path=settings.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH,
                         desired_capabilities=capabilities,
                         service_log_path=settings.DRIVER_LOG_PATH)
    selenium.maximize_window()
    return (selenium, proxy)

class BaseGATestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.proxy = robot_globals['proxy']
        self.selenium = robot_globals['selenium']
....

class TestHomePage(BaseGATestCase):
    def test_01_homepage_utme_vars(self):
        self.proxy.new_har('home_page')
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (settings.SERVER_URL_TO_TEST, '/'))
```

This code works correctly usually. But once or twice in month system launches the browser
but does not load the url in it. Browser just waits but the page does not get loaded at all.

However browser can load page without self.proxy.new_har('..'). The code likes this works:

```
class TestHomePage(BaseGATestCase):
    def test_01_homepage_utme_vars(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (settings.SERVER_URL_TO_TEST, '/'))
```

server.log:

```
INFO 10/09 03:09:18 n.l.b.p.j.h.HttpSer~ - Version Jetty/5.1.x
INFO 10/09 03:09:18 n.l.b.p.j.u.Contain~ - Started HttpContext[/,/]
INFO 10/09 03:09:18 n.l.b.p.j.h.SocketL~ - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:9159
INFO 10/09 03:09:18 n.l.b.p.j.u.Contain~ - Started    net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.jetty.jetty.Server@6a1192e9
INFO 10/09 03:10:25 n.l.b.p.j.u.Threade~ - Stopping Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=9154]
```

It is really weird for me because last time I couldn't fix this problem, but it was fixed itself the next day. I do not understand why. And now I have the same problem. It would be great if anyone knows how I can fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've had this exact same issue. Are you having it only with Chrome, or all browsers? I'd try creating the drivers, and setting their proxies in different ways. Maybe that would help?